# Cursor not in right location and can go beyond $ sign in VSCode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I connect to remote host in VSCode. Then let' say I type the following command in VSCode terminal

```
sh ./environment/activate_python_jupyter.sh
```

and then I realize that I should use the **pyspark** one instead of  the **python** one, so I use up arrow to find the above command, and use left/right arrows to locate my cursor to modify **thon** to **spark**. The modified command looks like this before I hit enter

```
sh ./environment/activate_pyspark_jupyter.sh
```

However, after I hit the enter I find out that the modified command is not the one I see before (checked by up arrow), it might be something like this

```
sh ./environment/actispark_python_jupyter.sh
```

I try several times and each time the modified command looks good/turns to a different and wrong one before/after I hit enter. I finally realize that it is because the cursor was actually not located in the right place when I modified the command, although it looked good before I hit enter.

More interestingly, my cursor can go beyond the $ (dollar sign) when I use up arrow to find a command and move the cursor using the left arrow.

This looks like a cursor location bug. Have someone met with such issue and happen to know a solution?

Comment: Same issue here. Do you find it's only when using a remote host?

Comment: @EfraimBart Yes it is only on remote mode. I doubt if it is because I used the SSH extension called 'ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.81.VSIX'. I uninstalled that extension and used 'SSH FS' instead, and the issued seems disappear. I will leave it for a while to make sure if that is the reason. Are you using any SSH related extension?

Comment: Yes, I regularly use the Microsoft remote extensions, though the issue seems to be happening in codespaces as well.

Comment: did you ever find a fix? I have the same issue